# Assigning Name to Each Points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, network-analyst

My python code :

```
import arcpy

arcpy.FeatureToLine_management("Closestroute", "Featureline", "0.0001 Meters", "ATTRIBUTES")

#Generate points along lines for every 1 km

arcpy.GeneratePointsAlongLines_management("Featureline", "splitPoints", "DISTANCE", "1000 Meters", "", "NO_END_POINTS")

#Split line at point for every 1 km roads,search radius = 20 meters

arcpy.SplitLineAtPoint_management("Featureline", "splitPoints", "split1kpoints", "20 Meters")

#I added SS field into splitPoints, then I assigned name for each rows.(s1, s2, s3, ...) 

cursor=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("splitPoints","SS")

i = 0

for row in cursor:

row[0] = 's' + str(i)

i += 1

cursor.updateRow(row)

del row

del cursor
```

My problem is:

I am trying to assign one name for each points. However, when one route are used by more than one start points like blue arrow in the picture below, I obtained more than one segments name for this route. I am trying to get just one segments name for each points for this route. (showed with blue arrow) for both start points.

How I can deal with this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Please format your code legibly by using the original code and the `{}` format button.

Comment: With the DA cursor, can you check if the Name is blank, then populate?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like points are stacking up due to duplicate line features or line feature segments. I'd perform a [delete identical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm) on your output point feature class, either before or after your cursor.

```
shpFld = arcpy.Describe ("splitPoints").shapeFieldName
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management ("splitPoints", shpFld)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helps a lot !!  Since I am assigning name in order, although one segment is used by two shortest paths, in attribute table, shows for just one start-end point shortest path. I have posted my guestion. If you can take a look, I will be appreciated for that.  @Emil Brundage